# Avoiding lazy evaluation in spark dataframe

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, etl

I have list if files and I do the below operations on them

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;

for(File file :files){
    df = spark.read.csv(file)
    df = df.withColumn("last_update_date",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), "PST"))))
    Thread.sleep(500)
Finaldf = Finaldf.union(df)
}
```

And then I will perform de-duplication based on the column that I added. I came to know that because of spark's lazy evaluation all the files are having the same `last_update_date` value and eventually I am removing the wrong duplicate from my final DF.

**I have tried the following but I still see the issue sometimes**

1. using `df.cache()`
2. loading the df into a temp table after reading each file with some time delay.

As mentioned, After trying the above 2 solutions I could see that issue less frequently but I would like to completely eliminate it.

Comment: Why are you using time anyway? Use an integer. So the first file gets 1, the second file gets 2, the third file gets 3 etc., and then remove duplicates based on that integer. You'll save yourself the wait between loops, too.

Comment: it seems you won't use df in between loading read.csv calls in your example code - if this is just illustrative it'd be better to provide code that shows the Finaldf = union call in the for loop.

Comment: Value for "last_update_date" can be generated in Java code loop, and assigned, for avoid lazy initialization:  .withColumn("last_update_date",lit(last_update_date_generated_in_java_string))

Comment: using the time is my requirement @RealSkeptic,

Comment: @pasha701 That's a nice workaround and I will give it a try , But Any idea why the cache function was not able to enforce the functions to be evaluated.

Comment: Method 'cache' is not an action, and not affecting evaluation; it is just a marker to store evaluation results in memory.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark's lazy evaluation, you are using `current_timestamp()` in this case all rows get the same timestamp value when the action is finally triggered that's why you are facing issue. RealSkeptic suggestion to use int values instead of current_timestamp.

If you want to ensure that each file has a unique timestamp then:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;

// Add python lib of time
import time

// assuming the files in array formate
Finaldf = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)

for (file in files){
    df = spark.read.csv(file)
    
    // Get current time in milliseconds at first using time lib
    current_time_in_millisec = int(time.mktime(Date().timetuple()) * 1000)

    // Your line of code
    //df = df.withColumn("last_update_date",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), "PST"))))
    
    // New way of this: Here used lit() function to add static value at first then add the current timestamp
    df = df.withColumn("last_update_date", from_unixtime(lit(current_time_in_millisec / 1000).cast('long')))
    
    Finaldf = Finaldf.union(df)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    //Thread.sleep(500)
}
//Finaldf = Finaldf.union(df)
```

I commented your code and side by side written improved version.